# Flutter, cloud fire store query method, where not working properly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a search feature in an app where I search for a store (from the Cloud Firestore database) using their query method where but I keep getting the same result, which is the first store on "list". No matter what I search.

```
                  StreamBuilder(
                    builder: (context , snapshot) {
                      if(snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                        );
                      }//end if

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        QuerySnapshot querysnapshot =  snapshot.data;
                        List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querysnapshot.docs;
                        processData(documents);
                        print("here : " + stores[0].name.toString());
                        print("search: " + searchQuery);
                        print("array length: " + stores.length.toString());
                        return Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemBuilder: (context , index) {
                              return Center(
                                child: Text(stores[index].name.toString()),
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: stores.length,
                          ),
                          height: height,
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Snapshot has no data"),
                          ),
                        );
                      }//end if-else
                    },
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Stores').where('name' , isEqualTo: name).snapshots(),
                  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry I made an idiotic mistake. I forgot to use to search variable instead of the name variable in the where function!

Comment: there are no intelligent mistakes :) , please mark your answer as correct, and put the actual "search variable".